# Resize and re-aggregate whisper stats

Tags: graphite, whisper

Our monitoring system dumps metrics into Graphite does so once per minute, and has a retention of `1min:2d,5min:20d,30min:120d,6h:2y`. However I've recently added monitors that run on a 5-minute period, and I've found that:

- The 1 minute points are four zeroes and an actual value, repeating of course.
- The 5+ minute points are all zeroes, likely because my xFilesFactor is higher than 0.2 and the aggregation just doesn't happen at all.

What I'd like to do is simply create a new Whisper file with the new retentions, [and no wasted space] and then import/re-aggregate the data into it. From what I've found `whiper-resize.py` is supposed to be the right tool.

As a test I've been doing:

```
whisper-resize.py \
  --newfile=/tmp/foo.wsp \
  --aggregate --aggregationMethod=max \
  --xFilesFactor=0.1 \
  --force \
  quotas/us-central1CPUS/CPUS.wsp \
  5min:20d 30min:120d 6h:2y
```

But after this operation completes `foo-wsp` is just filled with zeroes.

What's the deal?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change xFilesFactor for target files, like

```
whisper-resize.py --xFilesFactor=0.0 --nobackup quotas/us-central1CPUS/CPUS.wsp 1min:2d 5min:20d 30min:120d 6h:2y
```

You will not waste space - whisper format has fixed file size anyway. Please see details in http://obfuscurity.com/2012/04/Unhelpful-Graphite-Tip-9

Comment: Well I meant "wasted space" as in "space used to store zeroes" which was 80% of the space in the 1min point set, or really 100% of the space in the 1min set since it's one point every five minutes. The whole point is to do away with the 1min storage and just go directly to 5min. Shaving off a few kB per file can make a real difference when storing many thousands of files.

Comment: Well, not sure is whisper-resize can do that.

Comment: I have tested with version 0.9.16 and the correct method is to use separated arguments.

Comment: Yes, you're right, acxcording to docs you should use separated arguments. Thanks! Amended.